# Marshaling and undefined attributes/classes

Tags: ruby

I am using ruby marshaling to send data between two clients.  Each client has a set of class definitions which they will use to help load the marshaled data. The definitions are stored in an external ruby file which they can load anytime they want (but usually when they start up)

A simple use case would be

- Client A marshal dumps the data and sends it to client B
- Client B marshal loads the data and then writes it out to a file

However, sometimes one client is sending data that contains objects that isn't defined in the other client's definitions, in which case the other client should update its definitions accordingly.

It might be a new instance variable that should be added to the definition of class `xyz` or it might be a new class completely.

`Marshal#Load` currently just throws an exception when it runs into an undefined variable (eg: undefined class/method `abc`).

Is there a way for me to take this exception and update the definitions accordingly so that the client can happily read the data and write it out?

All classes will contain data that Marshal already knows how to encode/decode, such as strings, arrays, hashes, numbers, etc. There won't be any data that requires custom `dump`/`load` methods.

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be to automatically create the class (and constant hierarchy, i.e. `Foo::Bar::Baz`) and make the class autorespond to attribute access attempts.

```
class AutoObject
  def method_missing(*args,&b)
    if args.size == 1
      name = args[0]
      if instance_variable_defined? "@#{name}"
        self.class.send :attr_accessor, name
        send(*args)
      else
        super
      end
    elsif args.size == 2 && args[0].to_s[/=$/]
      name = args[0].to_s[0...-1]
      if instance_variable_defined? "@#{name}"
        self.class.send :attr_accessor, name
        send(*args)
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end

def Marshal.auto_load(data)
  Marshal.load(data)
rescue ArgumentError => e
  classname = e.message[%r(^undefined class/module (.+)$), 1]
  raise e unless classname

  classname.split("::").inject(Object) do |outer, inner|
    if !outer.const_defined? inner
      outer.const_set inner, Class.new(AutoObject)
    else
      outer.const_get inner
    end
  end
  retry
end
```

This could easily be extended to log all classes created, and even to determine what instance variables they might have. Which could then aid you in updating the files, perhaps programatically.